# Unable to read HDD content Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, lubuntu, hard-drive, media, plex

I had a pretty old computer laying around (Dell Dimension 1100) and last week, when I heard about ''Plex Media Center'' I tought it would be a perfect computer to install the server on it. So I've installed multiple HDD in it and installed the latest Lubuntu version. I first had problem mounting all of them but after a bit of research on the web, it was ok. Then I've tranfered all my movies, music and photos on the hard drives, I installed the plex media server. After adding the music directories etc. I've remarked that I'm was not able to see and read the files on the drive. In the file explorer it keep spinning and loading and in plex it just detect's nothing! I also tried with multiple others files explorers and it does the same thing.

If you know how to help me, it would help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but It looks like the HDDs are faulty. 
I had a similar problem (hdd was looped on searching) with a defective hard drive.
How many HDD are connected?
Can you remove one or more drives and try to read it on a different machine?

Comment: I know the hard drive is not the proble because when I plug it with a usb adapter on my laptop I can use the drive without any problem but thanks for your answer it's apreciated that you took the time ;) bye!